# IPN PayPal - Couldn't resolve host

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've a problem with IPN PayPal. Since one year about, we don't have any problem. And since 3 days, IPN PayPal doesn't work.

In my error log I have this error :

> [05-May-2016 16:53:36 UTC] [2016-05-05 16:53 UTC] Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: Couldn't resolve host 'www.paypal.com'

Have you an idea?

Comment: I use this... https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

Comment: You must edit resolver dns !!
/etc/resolv.conf :